# Using variables defined in an included file (included by another file) in the including file in php

Tags: php

Let's say I have three files that have the following code

File 1: firstfile.php

```
 
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "mydbname";
    $dbuser = "myuserid";
    $dbpass = "mypass";
    $dblink = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname,$dblink);

    $errorlogs = "c:/wamp/www/smstrunk/tmp/weblogs.log";
    $displaycount = 2;
    $querylimit = "LIMIT $displaycount";
    $maximportfilesize = 2097152;
```

File 2: secondfile.php

```
include("firstfile.php");

//Returns the GET/POST parameter value
    function getPassedParam($param){

        if(isset($_POST[$param])) $value = $_POST[$param];
        elseif(isset($_GET[$param])) $value = $_GET[$param];
        else $value = "";

        return $value;
    }
//##########################################

// DB Functions
    function selectSQL($qry, $dblink){

        global $errorlogs;

        $result = mysql_query($qry, $dblink);
        if (!$result) {
            log2File("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
            return false;
        }
        log2File($qry);

        return $result;
    }

    function updateSQL($qry, $dblink){

        $result = mysql_query($qry, $dblink);
        if (!$result) {
            log2File("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
            return false;
        }
        log2File($qry);

        return mysql_affected_rows($dblink);
    }

    function insertSQL($qry, $dblink){
            echo $displaycount;
        $result = mysql_query($qry, $dblink);
        if (!$result) {
            log2File("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
            return false;
        }
        log2File($qry);

        return mysql_insert_id();

    }
//##########################################

//Mailing Functions
    function auto_reg_mail($to, $message){

        $subject = 'Registration Confirmation';
        $headers = 'From: noreply@smstrunk.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
//##########################################


//Logging Function
    function log2File($message, $file=NULL){

        global $errorlogs;
        if($file == NULL)$file = $errorlogs;

        $msg = date("Y-m-d H:m:s") . " [" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "] $message \n";
        error_log($msg, 3, $file);
    }
//##########################################


// Application Specific Functions
//  1. Get customer id from msisdn
    function getCustID($msisdn, $lowner, $dblink, $alias = ""){

        //Check if msisdn already exists for this user
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT custid, mstatus FROM msisdn WHERE number = '%s' AND owner = '$lowner'", mysql_real_escape_string($msisdn));
        $rsmsisdn = selectSQL($sql, $dblink);

        if($rwmsisdn = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsmsisdn)){
            $custID = $rwmsisdn['custid'];
            $mstatus = $rwmsisdn['mstatus'];
            $sql = sprintf("UPDATE msisdn SET mstatus = 0, alias = '%s' WHERE custID = '$custID'", mysql_real_escape_string($alias));
            updateSQL($sql, $dblink);
        }else{
        // if not insert number
            $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO msisdn (number, owner, alias) VALUES ('%s', '$lowner', '%s')", $msisdn, mysql_real_escape_string($alias));
            $custID = insertSQL($sql, $dblink);
        }
        return $custID;
    }

?>
```

File 3: third.php

```
include ("secondfile.php");

echo $dblink;
```

Why is $dblink giving me undefined variable when I have already defined it in firstfile.php? Does the php compiler/interpreter allow limited levels of include

Comment: The example you show should work. Are you in the context of any other functions with this? Are you calling all includes through a filesystem path?

Comment: when do you ever use that function?

Comment: @Neal
Forget the function. Am not using it in the code above

Comment: @yankitwizzy... so show us the code **you are using** or else this question is meaningless... (@Pekka)

Comment: @Pekka
Am not calling includes through a file system path. If I was and the files were not seen, I would have gotten a different error

Comment: @Neal
Is the question not clear enough. My problem is just that myVar is showing me that it is undefined when I have defined it. Just forget about the function and look at the other things there. Pls

Comment: @yankitwizzy -- what do ur actual files look like?...

Comment: My guess is that something is unsetting it. Looking at the full code would help.

Comment: Well if you have it exactly as above then it will work, I have just tried your example and from the third.php file when run it displays the value.

Comment: Maybe something goes wrong with establishing `$dblink`? Can you try echoing it in File 1?

Answer (score 1):

> [I] am not calling includes through a file system path

`include()` fetches a file, and then executes the PHP source code in it.

If you are using a `http://` path, every include will get interpreted separately, in its own parser instance. That way, variables defined in one include will not make it to the other.

You need to use filesystem paths (or make your http includes *emit* source code instead of executing it).

Comment: @Pekka 
Hmmm nice. Please how do I make http includes emit source code?

Comment: @yankitwizzy you would have to make the script output the PHP code using `echo()`, or use a different extension that doesn't get parsed (like `.txt`). However, that way, the PHP code becomes visible to everyone else. If at all possible, you want to use file paths.

Comment: @Pekka
Pls by default what is used - file system path or http path?

Comment: @yankit what do you mean by default? Can you make an example? If you use `filename.php` without anything, it will default to the filesystem path.

Comment: @Pekka
Then in my case am using the file system path and I still can't understand why am getting undefined variable errors

Comment: @yankitwizzy Just checking: you do have all three files in the same directory (or in a directory in the include path), don't you? And you don't get any error messages (warnings) after including `secondfile.php`, other than the notice about the undefined `$dblink`?

Comment: @Viktor
Yes I have all the files in the same directory. And yes no other error messages after including seconfile.php just that $dblink is not defined. Am really confused here

Comment: @yankitwizzy What about the opening tags? They weren't included in the code example. If you use short tag notation `<?`, try replacing them with `<?php`.